# Javascript "this" scope giving different result depending on the way it is called

Tags: javascript, scope, this

All,

This is the code:

```
var Person = function (name) {

  this.name = name;

  this.printName = function(){
    console.log("My name is " + this.name);
  }

};


var p = new Person("Steve");

var funcRef = p["printName"];

p.printName();//Works

p["printName"]();//Works
funcRef();//returns incorrect value
```

Find a working example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/57LS6oXPfqccAWf6uqQV?p=preview

My question is what's the difference between the last two? I'm accessing the object method in the same way, the only difference is the way it's being called.

Why does it return a difference result?

First time I have come across this in javascript. I understand it's in a difference scope but i don't know how it got decoupled from the object which is what I'd like to understand.

Thanks

Steve

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: `this` is late-bound in JS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

javascript bind the `this` keyword when you call the function on the object directly.

With `test.fn()`, `this` will be `test` inside `fn`. Same with `test['fn']()`. But if you do `var fn = test.fn; fn()`, `this` will be the global root (`window` in a browser) inside `fn`.

You can force the `this` inside a function like this : `var fn = test.fn.bind(test);`

More informations here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 2):

Case1 :
'this' always takes the context of the object with respect to which its called.

In p.printName() the context is p therefore 'this' references the Person object that 'p' refers to.

Case2:
But, when you direct 'funcRef' to p's method it loses this context and 'this' references the global object.

The global object can be different depending on your js environment (like the browser context or node and so on).

That is why you see different results.

Answer (score 2):

As other answer say, `this` is bound when you call the function. A common way to keep the reference to the object is to use something like this:

```
var Person = function (name) {

  var self = this; // Keep a reference to this object for later use
  self.name = name;

  self.printName = function(){
    console.log("My name is " + self.name);
  }

};
```

Answer (score 2):

How this scope behaves is already explained by above answers, here is best practice for 'this' usages, use 'this' as a new variable called 'self', see below code, this way you have better control and less error due to wrong usages of this scope.

```
var Person = function (name) {
  var self=this;
  self.name = name;

  self.printName = function(){
    console.log("My name is " + self.name);
  }
};
```